# How to print All the Sub-Arrays from an Array with given range?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to print all the sub arrays from a given array with range 2.for
example

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

for the above array sub arrays of range 2 are like this

```
{1,2};
{2,3};
{3,4};
```

I have a class which prints all the sub arrays of an array like below

```
 public class PrintSubarrayMain {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        PrintSubarrayMain psm=new PrintSubarrayMain();
        int arr[]= {1,2,3,4};
        psm.printSubArray(arr);
    }

    void printSubArray(int arr[])
    {

        int n=arr.length;
        for (int i=0; i <n; i++) //This loop will select start element
        {
            for (int j=i; j<n; j++)   //This loop will select end element
            {
                for (int k=i; k<=j; k++) //This loop will print element from start to end

                {
                    System.out.print( arr[k]+" "); 
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which gives output like this

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
2 
2 3 
2 3 4 
3 
3 4 
4
```

but i am not able to print sub arrays with specific range?please help me out

Comment: What do you mean with specific range? I am not sure what you want to achive

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < N - subArraySize) { printSubArrayStartingAt(arr, i); }`

Comment: you are not passing the range value anywhere in your code.

Comment: @MatthiasLauber i have mentioned in the question..that need to group array by some values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class PrintSubarrayMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PrintSubarrayMain psm = new PrintSubarrayMain();
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        psm.printSubArray(arr);
    }

    void printSubArray(int arr[]) {     
        for (int i = 0; i <arr.length-1; i++) {
            int [] subArr=new int[2];
            System.arraycopy(arr,i, subArr, 0, 2);
            for (int j=0;j<2;j++)
                System.out.print(subArr[j]+ " ");
            System.out.println();
        }       
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 
2 3 
3 4
```

**Update:** doing it without using `System.arraycopy` as requested by you

```
public class PrintSubarrayMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PrintSubarrayMain psm = new PrintSubarrayMain();
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        psm.printSubArray(arr);
    }

    void printSubArray(int arr[]) {     
        for (int i = 0; i <arr.length-1; i++) {
            for(int j=i;j<i+2;j++)
                System.out.print(arr[j]+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }       
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 
2 3 
3 4
```

**Update:** Adding range as you have requested

```
public class PrintSubarrayMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PrintSubarrayMain psm = new PrintSubarrayMain();
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int range = 3;
        psm.printSubArray(arr, range);
    }

    void printSubArray(int arr[], int range) {
        if (range <= arr.length)
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - range + 1; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < i + range; j++)
                    System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        else
            System.out.println("Range is greater than the size of the array");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 
2 3 4
```

Comment: Yes, the above code prints output but i should not use any pre defined methods or Collections only by for loops logic

Comment: yes it almost fulfilled my requirements but how to make it exception free for range 3..

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of second loop. You can declare a variable range and then find **end value** as **j=i+range** and  outermost loop should have terminating condition as **i<=n-range**

```
void printSubArray(int arr[])
{
    int range=3;
    int n=arr.length;
    for (int i=0; i <=n-range; i++) //This loop will select start element
    {       
            int j=i+range;
            for (int k=i; k<j; k++) //This loop will print element from start to end

            {
                System.out.print( arr[k]+" "); 
            }
            System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly this is what i want.. but how to handle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ...for range 3 ...

Comment: Declare a variable 'range' and replace n-1 with n-range in first loop and j=i+2 with j=i+range.